# Find dependency from json recursively

Tags: javascript

```
data = [
    {
        "StoryID":"B-1",
        "Dependencies":[{"StoryID":"B-2",},{"StoryID":"B-3",}]
    },
    {
        "StoryID":"B-2",
        "Dependencies":[]
    },
    {
        "StoryID":"B-3",
        "Dependencies":[{"StoryID":"B-4",},{"StoryID":"B-5",}]
    },
    {
        "StoryID":"B-4",
        "Dependencies":[]
    },
    {
        "StoryID":"B-5",
        "Dependencies":[{"StoryID":"B-6"}]
    },
    {
        "StoryID":"B-6",
        "Dependencies":[]
    }
]
```

```
var storyID = "B-3";
get_d(data,storyID ,Dependencies = []);

function get_d(data,storyID ,Dependencies = []){
    temp = []
    for(i in data){
        if(storyID == data[i]['StoryID']){
            depend = data[i]['Dependencies'];
            for(j in depend){
                Dependencies.push(depend[j]["StoryID"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to find Dependent story for particular story from above data, I am getting only one level data using above function, but I want output like this recursively,

```
{
  "B-3": [
    {
      "B-4": [

      ],
      "B-5": [
        {
          "Number": "B-6",
        },
        {
          "Number": "B-7",
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your function isn't recursive. In your loop through the dependencies of the current level, should be calling your function again (recursing) for each dependency ID. (To avoid circular references you should check if a dependency is already in the collected list, and skip the add/recurse step for that dependency.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert the data to a hash table and get the dependencies by using a recursion.

It is still quite unclear, what you want with the leaves.

```js
function getDependencies(data, StoryID) {
    function getProperty(k) {
        return function (o) { return o[k]; };
    }

    function getD(r, StoryID) {
        r[StoryID] = object[StoryID].reduce(getD, {});
        return r;
    }

    var object = data.reduce(function (r, o) {
            r[o.StoryID] = (o.Dependencies || []).map(getProperty('StoryID'));
            return r;
        }, {});

    return [StoryID].reduce(getD, {});
}

var data = [{ StoryID: "B-1", Dependencies: [{ StoryID: "B-2" }, { StoryID: "B-3" }] }, { StoryID: "B-2", Dependencies: [] }, { StoryID: "B-3", Dependencies: [{ StoryID: "B-4" }, { StoryID: "B-5" }] }, { StoryID: "B-4", Dependencies: [] }, { StoryID: "B-5", Dependencies: [{ StoryID: "B-6" }] }, { StoryID: "B-6", Dependencies: [] }],
    result =  getDependencies(data, 'B-3')

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: this is es 6 code ... is it possible to make in normal javascript ?

Comment: I m getting error Cannot read property 'Dependencies' of undefined

Comment: then your object does not contain any `Dependencies` property.

Comment: its throwing this error if dependent story not available in main data, can we add check for that? please check this snippet 
https://jsfiddle.net/jocz3sfr/

Comment: you could add a default array, like `(o.Dependencies || [])` please see edit.